# WordPress new image size not showing correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a new image size and have it selectable in the media modal.

I have checked that a new, correct sized image is being created ie 670px wide

But the modal window is showing it as being 604px wide and when inserted you get:

```
<img width="604" height="453" alt="two-new-honeys" src=".../two-new-honeys-670x503.jpg" class="..">
```

IE its putting in the right image, but adding in wrong width and height values in the html

What can I do to get the right width / height

In functions.php I have added:

```
// add new image size(s)
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bsb_add_image_size' );
function bsb_add_image_size() {
  add_image_size( '2-column', 670 ); // 670 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
}


add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        '2-column' => __( '2 Column width' ),
    ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was down to a theme specific variable called $content_width that was set for the theme 2013 at 604px  - therefore the media modal was overriding my image at 670px and scaling it down the the size set by $content_width.

Solution is to reset $content_width=xxx within functions.php

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width

Answer (score 0):

In case someone might need it - there is a way to specify $content_width by template name. Code have to be placed in your functions.php

```
<?php

//adjust $content_width only for chosen template
function custom_adjust_content_width() {
    global $content_width;

    if ( is_page_template( 'my-template.php' ) )
        $content_width = 640;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_adjust_content_width' );
?>
```